# Using node-adyen-encrypt in ReactJs Application

Tags: reactjs, npm, adyen

When I try to integrate it in my React app..

I used "Origin key" provided by Adyen as the "adyenKey"

```
var adyenKey ='pub.v2.8015565304900201.aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYubGxlc3VvcmFjLmNvbQ.kSRpd4gWCUF0K1E2WaXAODtk3_HXGy9q9wyFi8TAu6s';
var options = {}; // See adyen-encrypt.js for details
```

```
 number : '5577 0000 5577 0004', // 'xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx'
 cvc : '737', //'xxx'
 holderName : 'customer', // 'John Doe'
 expiryMonth : '10', //'MM'
 expiryYear : '2020', // 'YYYY'
 generationtime : new Date().toISOString() // new Date().toISOString()};
```

```
 cseInstance.validate(cardData);
 var dataEncrypted = cseInstance.encrypt(cardData);
```

I used these Dummy data.

It gives me `cseInstance.encrypt(cardData)` this as a `Malford public key`.

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

node-adyen-encrypt uses the deprecated Client Side Encryption (CSE) integration. You should be using 
[secured fields](https://docs.adyen.com/checkout/api-integration/build-your-own-payment-form/#step-2-collect-shopper-details-with-secured-fields) which is the successor to CSE.

Comment: How should I include the script in React component ? 
If I use the approch by including script in "componentWillMount()" It gives me a error of "To process payments with Adyen - don't use Protected Browser." of "Kaspersky Internet Security " 

So what you suggest me to do.

Comment: That usually is from the domain specified in the origin key doesn't match the url of the page itself.